# QML fill ColumnLayout with createObject in a Component

Tags: qt, tabs, qml, components, tabview

i want to add a Component dynamically to an ColumnLayout in a TabView/Tab. But i've not found a possibility to do this. The problem is that i have no correct parent reference to my ColumnLayout for the createObject call.
Because the Tab dynamically loads a Component I've encapsulated the ColumnLayout in a Component.

In the QML Debugger i can solve the following path: **objForm.tabView.tabStatus.tabStatusLoader.colLayout**, but i cant use this as an correct parent.

It seems not be in the scope.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'tabStatus' of undefined
```

**ObjForm.ui.qml**

```
Item {
    id: item1
    width: 400
    height: 400

    property QtObject object

    property Component compLayout

    TabView {
        id: tabView
        anchors.fill: parent
        Tab {
            id: tabStatus
            title: "status"
            Loader {
                id: tabStatusLoader
                sourceComponent: compLayout
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ObjForm.qml**

```
ObjectViewForm {
    id: objForm
    anchors.fill: parent
    object: someObj

    compLayout: Component {
        id: layoutComp
        ColumnLayout {
            id: colLayout
            spacing: 2
        }
    }

    onObjectChanged: {
        // Here i want to add the someLabel Component to the ColumnLayout
        someLabel.createObject(*PARENT*)
    }

Component {
    id: someLabel

    Row {
        property string text
        property string label

        spacing: 5

        Label {
            text: parent.label
        }

        Label {
            text: parent.text
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this or can make a better suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I've found a solution by myself. Instead to include the ColumnLayout into the Component, i've pulled it out and made an alias property to publish it. With this it was possible to add objects to my ColumnLayout. But the ColumnLayout got the wrong parent(objForm) instead of the Component.

A Component cant be a parent because a QQuickItem* is expected instead of a QObject* and additional can't include properties except for 'id'. Therefore a dummy Item was needed.

To reparent the ColumnLayout the Item needs a Component.onCompleted function where the parent will be set.

```
ObjectViewForm {
        id: objForm
        anchors.fill: parent
        object: someObj

        property alias componentLayout: colLayout

        compLayout: Component {
            id: layoutComp
            Item {
                id: dummy
                Component.onCompleted:  {
                    colLayout.parent = dummy
                }
            }
        }

        ColumnLayout {
            id: colLayout
            spacing: 2
        }
```